# Get array item from arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am modifying my question to make it more understandable. 
I have the following arraylist

```
ArrayList<AnotherClass> exmapleName = new ArrayList<AnotherClass>();
// AnotherClass is a class I created, I store objects of the class in this array, the code to this doesn't matter this works.
```

Inside of exampleName I have different types of data

```
public AnotherClass (String someString,  int someInt, int anotherInt, int[] intArray, ArrayList<Integer> arrayList)
//Header of the constructor
```

Now what I need to do is access and store arrayList[0]. But I need to do it once the object has been created so there is actually something inside arrayList.

This is what I've tried but doesn't seem to work

```
         AnotherClass test1 = exampleName.get(1);
        ArrayList<Integer> test2 = test1.arrayList;
        int test3 = test2.arrayList[0];
// I broke it down into separate lines to make it more understandable
```

compiler errors are as follows

```
cannot find symbol
                    int test3 = test2.arrayList[0];
symbol:   variable arrayList
location: variable test2 of type ArrayList<Integer>
```

1 error

Comment: You have an ArrayList of int[]? It is this data your type.@Blueaddiction

Answer (score 2):

If you're having a "normal" array, you can simply access the `i`-th element, with the index, as `myArrayList.get(1).normalArray[i]`.

If you need to process the array, consider storing it into a local copy and access from it.

```
int[] numbers = myArrayList.get(1);
for(Integer num : numbers){
  // Process the numbers array.
  System.out.print(num);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before but, I need to store the variable as an int but it requires an integer array R.java:70: error: array required, but ArrayList<Integer> found

Comment: @Blueaddiction So you're saying that `normalArray` is declared as an `ArrayList<Integer>`?  You didn't say that in your original post.  You said "int array" which everybody else has misinterpreted.  Please show us more of the code.

Comment: I said the main array is an integer arraylist which inside has an int array. I'll post some more code when I go back to it taking a break

Comment: I've modified the main post to reflect the problem more clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
 int arr[] = myArrayList.get(1);
```

access like,

```
int first=arr[0];
```

Comment: actually wait it didnt work, error: incompatible types: //my other class -->(anotherClass) cannot be converted to int[]
                        int[] test1 = eQuestion.get(1);

Comment: can you please post some more code so that I can figure out if its still not working for you.